# Video playback asks about security timer reset

Tags: java, blackberry, video

I am developing a BlackBerry app which can play video. The first time the video starts playing (works fine) it asks with a dialog,

"The application xyz is attempting to reset the security timer. "

Checkbox:

Do not ask again

And the option
Allow / Deny

If allow is choosen and the checkbox selected, the video plays without problem the next time. But is it a way to remove this security timer question before the video is even played?

[This](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Security-Timer-dialog-appearing-during-video-playback-using/m-p/719235/highlight/false#M138762) is a related or [same issue over at the RIM support site](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Security-Timer-dialog-appearing-during-video-playback-using/m-p/719235/highlight/false#M138762).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog you are seeing is the OS prompting the user to grant your application permission to a restricted API call. Even though you are not directly resetting the security timer in your code, it is being done on your behalf as part of your app. The best way to handle this is to prompt the user for permission the first time the user runs your app.

Below is a sample method that prompts the user for all permissions. You should call this the first time your application runs. You could be more selected in what you prompt for by calling permRequest.addPermission( int permission ) for only the permissions that you need. For example pass ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_IDLE_TIMER.

```
private static void assertHasPermissions() 
  {
    // Capture the current state of permissions and check against the
    // requirements.
    ApplicationPermissionsManager apm = ApplicationPermissionsManager.getInstance();
    ApplicationPermissions original = apm.getApplicationPermissions();
    ApplicationPermissions permRequest = new ApplicationPermissions();
    int[] permissions = original.getPermissionKeys();
    for ( int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++ ) 
    {
      permRequest.addPermission( i );
    }
    apm.invokePermissionsRequest( permRequest );
  }
```

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Enable-the-backlight-and-prevent-the-BlackBerry-device-screen/ta-p/444706

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess...

It may be that when you start playing the video, the OS assumes a request to reset the security timer so that the device will not lock while the video is playing. It may be easier to be sure if you let us know what version of the device software you are running, and what version of the API you are programming with.

Comment: 6.0 for both device OS and API I am coding against.

Comment: Maybe this could be fixed by explicitly resetting the security timer or disable it?  Interesting...

Comment: It seems you know more about these things. Could you please enlighten?

Comment: Accepting. Will assume there is no way to make this happen without saving in that dialog.